# How to deal with this cyclic module dependency in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cyclic-dependency

Simplified version of hierarchy:

```
module A where

import MyState

data A a = A (StateT MyState IO a) deriving (...)
```

Now there is a module MyState:

```
module MyState where

import SomeType

data MyState = MyState { st :: SomeType, ... }
```

Finally the module that introduces cyclic dependency:

```
module SomeType where

import A

data SomeType = SomeType { f :: A (), ... }
```

As you can see my SomeType imports A because we need it for one of our fields. And A is importing state which imports sometype which introduces the cyclic dependency.

What would be the way to resolve this cyclic dependency? Thanks.

Comment: Technically there's a notion of an `.hsboot` file which allows you to forward declare things, but nobody uses them. Better is to define them all in the same file, often called `Internal` and then import that file in all three of `A`, `MyState`, and `SomeTime` where you can define further operations if you like.

Comment: J. Abrahamson: I tried to put them into one file but the problem is that there is a cyclic dependency within that file.

If i put first "data A" then "data MyState" and then "data SomeType" then the compiler says that it doesn't know about MyState (which is in state transformer)

And any other shuffling of the data types results in an error. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: GHC guide: [How to compile mutually recursive modules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#mutual-recursion). If you can, however, avoid this.

Comment: So MyState is in the same file but GHC can't find MyState? That sounds odd...

Comment: @ksaveljev (In a separate question, perhaps, but...) Can you give a minimal example of a single-module version that has an error, together with the exact error?

Comment: @ksaveljev Within a single file Haskell usually has completely co-recursive bindings. This can be broken if you're using any Template Haskell, however. To fix this merely move all of the TH declarations below all of the co-recursive declarations.